# Everyone have me

Tags: riddle

> Everyone have me;
>
> Without first two letters, I am not here;
>
> Without last two letters, I am a story;
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the answer

> "talent"? Without the first two letters it is "lent" (the past tense of "lend": an object that has been lent out is 'not here'), and without the last two it is "tale".

Comment: Correct! You are a riddle master!

Comment: And your talent is solving riddles!